# how to convert my PostgreSQL database table into CSV?

Tags: postgresql, export, postgresql-9.5, csv

i need to convert my PostgreSQL table into csv, how to do this?
i have visited many sites they suggest the PostgreSQL command to convert the table into CSV but i always get the error message.

the query i tried was :

```
COPY persons TO 'C:\tmp\persons_db.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

but PostgreSQL generates the error message as:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/tmp/banke.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open file "/tmp/banke.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

how to do this?
is there any other software or application that can convert the table into csv ?
if so then please suggest.
thank you all..

Comment: I got a patch into 10.0 for this btw, it now HINTs when you use server-side COPY and get a missing file or permissions error.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, PostgreSQL runs as "Network Service". "Network Service" will need write permissions to `c:\tmp` if you want it to write there.

Generally I recommend using `psql`'s `\copy` command instead of `copy`, as it doesn't need superuser permission in the db, and can write wherever your shell user can write.

Open up `cmd`:

```
> cd c:\tmp
> set PGDATABASE=$nameOfYourDatabase
> set PGUSER=$pgUsername
> set PGPASSWORD=$thePassword
> psql

> \copy persons to 'persons_db.csv' with (format csv, header true);
> \q
```